# change background of avator in listItem in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I wanna use a white background of avator.But it's gray in default.

```
<ListItem
    title={`${item.name}`}
    subtitle={item.sign_id}
    onPress= {()=>navigate('Login')}
    avatar={require('../img/aircondition.png')}
    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
/>
```

Any one knows that?

Comment: From where are you importing listview , some custom library or default react native listview ?

Comment: You can use  avatarStyle={{backgroundColor:'#FFF' }} .

Comment: It's default react native listView.And that's effect ,Thanks!

Comment: I have posted as an answer please accept and upvote so that others can get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `avatarStyle={{backgroundColor:'#FFF' }}` .